# Passing html <input type = "submit"> to js variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am a new coding student and having a hard time with an exercise I'm doing on my own, a simple coin-toss app.  I want user to input `n` number of tosses, then have js script toss coin `n` times. As I'm doing it in JSFiddle, I cut the form element because either `post` or `get` throws an error.  My issue right now is I cannot get value of `#myFlips` to store as `var i`. Any help is appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/Adam262/Fxrs3/3/

Below is my html:

```
<input type="number" id="myFlips" min="1" placeholder="How many flips?" 
onchange="save()">

<input type="submit" id="submit">
```

And my js:

```
function save() {
var i = document.getElementById("myFlips").value;}

function coin(i) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);}


while (i > 0) {
if (coin(i) == 1) {
    alert("Heads!");
} else alert("Tails!");
i--;}
```

Comment: It looks like you don't need the submit button at all. You already trigger the `save` function when the value of your input field changes. How are you triggering the `coin` function? Your variable `i` is defined in your `save` function so it won't be available outside of that function. Put the while loop in your `save` function.

Comment: you are not using i inside coin! what does coin() do? why do u pass i ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `var` keyword scopes the variable to the function.

When `save` runs, you assign a value to `i`, then the function ends. `i` is no longer in scope for anything, so it gets garbage collected.

Put `var i` outside the function and remove the `var` from the function.

---

If we look at your live example (please put enough code to reproduce your problem *in the question*) then you also need to move your `while` loop inside a function and call it at an appropriate time.

You are also defining your functions inside another function (`onload`), so they aren't globals, so the intrinsic event handler attribute can't see them (they are out of scope).

Don't use intrinsic event attributes, [add your event handlers with JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).